# nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/simpleJob.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am developing a Spring Batch application which has a dependency added. This dependency has a spring.xml file. I am scanning this xml file.calling the mxl file values from main method and displaying the out put.

I have added this xml file in root package  under config folder(src/main/java/config/simpleJob.xml) of my application. However I still see the exception listed below. Please can you anyone let me know what I am missing.and where i need to load the xml file in my application.

main method

```
public class HelloWorldTasklet implements Tasklet{



    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

 @Override
 public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext context)
   throws Exception {
  System.out.println(message);
  return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
 }

}
```

project structure
.SpringBatchSample
 |

|
 `-- src`
-- test
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |`-- example
         |           `-- SpringBatchExample
         |`-- HelloWorldTasklet.java
         |-- resources
         |
         |       `-- simpleJob.xml

Anyone help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance

i tried many solution which posted in different site,but still im getting the same issues

```
SEVERE: Job Terminated in error: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/simpleJob.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/simpleJob.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/simpleJob.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/simpleJob.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:592)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/simpleJob.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you post your project structure and main class?

Answer (score 1):

It is caused because of the wrong path.
From your description : The file is under **src/main/java/config/sampleJob.xml**

> I have added this xml file in root package under config folder(src/main/java/config/simpleJob.xml) of my application.

But from the exception, it can be noted that your program is trying to load the configuration from **[resources/simpleJob.xml]**

> SEVERE: Job Terminated in error: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/simpleJob.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/simpleJob.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

So correcting this path in your main class where you are loading the xml configuration file would fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error normally occurs when you right click on `com.akshay.codewithme` (shown in image) and you create a `.xml` file (in my case `spring.xml`).
What you can do is, right click on `src/main/java` and create a `.xml` file.

This is how I solved the issue. It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just want to throw in that I received this error after accidentally exporting my Spring project in Eclipse as an executable jar. Using the Spring Boot plugin with Maven fixed it.